# How to clear or reset cookies in Titanium HttpClient

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

When a person logs in using their creds and then logs out, any subsequent user can log in without providing correct creds. I have googled around but all in vein. I tried using clearCookies() on HttpClient object, but it gives error:

```
req.clearCookies(); //req is an object of HttpClient
```

I also tried resetting cookies via

req.setRequestHeader( "Cookie", null );

but nothing works. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

ENVIRONMENT DETAIL

iPad 5.0
Ti SDK 1.7.2

Comment: What error does `clearCookies()` give?

Comment: Because this function is introduced in SDK 1.8.1. You should use the latest one.

Comment: I started using 1.8.2 now. It does not gives error but still not clearing cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by specifying the full Host with "http://".

For example:

```
client.clearCookies("http://domaintyper.com");
```

It's not working without the http/https part.